# guardar os dados recebidos de um sensor numa lista em python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Como poderei guardar 100 valores recebidos de um sensor numa lista em python, para realizar posteriormente o cálculo da media deles?

Este é o código que tenho até agora:

```
#biblioteca para chamar ficheiros de outra extensão
from subprocess import check_output
import time

tam = 100

def criaVetor(valor):
    vec = []
    for i in range(tam): # vamos fazer isto tam (N) vezes
    vec.append((valor)) 
return vec

def Average(lst):
    return sum(lst)/len(lst)



while True:
    # chama o ficheiro em linguagem C em modo diferencial
    sensor_data= check_output(['./raspandmax','-d'], shell=False).decode()
    output_value = (sensor_data)# mostra o valor analógico lido no ADC
    adc_value = float(output_value)# converte o valor analógico de string para float
    #print(adc_value)# mostra o valor da conversÃ£o         
    print(criaVetor(adc_values)
    time.sleep(1)
```

quando mando correr o código ele adiciona sempre o mesmo valor lido e não os valores seguintes como tenho quando mando correr o código

```
[0.8554112934311049, 0.8554112934311049, 0.8554112934311049, 0.8554112934311049, 0.8554112934311049, 0.8554112934311049, 0.8554112934311049, 0.8554112934311049, 0.8554112934311049, 0.8554112934311049]
```

a ideia é ler os valores da seguinte forma, por exemplo:

```
valor 1 = 0.25
valor 2 = 0.26
valor 3 = 0.3
valor4 = ...
valor5 = ...
etc..
```

e inserir os valores da seguinte forma :
`[0.25, 0.26, 0.3, ..., ...]` e assim sucessivamente

Consegui esta solução para estar sempre a ler o vetor vec e ir fazendo a média do vetor total, pode não ser a melhor solução mas para o objectivo mostra o que quero perfeitamente.

```
  from subprocess import check_output
        import time

        tam = 1
        vec = []
        def criaVetor(valor):

            for i in range(tam): # vamos fazer isto tam (N) vezes
            vec.append((valor)) 
        return vec

        def Average(lst):
            return sum(lst)/len(lst)



        while True:
            # chama o ficheiro em linguagem C em modo diferencial
            sensor_data= check_output(['./raspandmax','-d'], shell=False).decode()
            output_value = (sensor_data)# mostra o valor analógico lido no ADC
            adc_value = float(output_value)# converte o valor analógico de string para float
            #print(adc_value)# mostra o valor da conversÃ£o         

            time.sleep(1)
            print("{0:.4f}".format(Average(criaVetor(adc_values)))
```

mas agora tenho uma dúvida que é criar um ciclo while para estar sempre a ler o ficheiro raspandmax e dar o valor, e posteriormente só queria dentro do while True que me mostrasse o valor analógico recebido

Comment: Faz um laço de repetição que lê o sensor e armazena na lista. Para adicionar um elemento a uma lista pode usar o método `list.append`.  Quer tentar? Qualquer coisa você pode [edit] a pergunta e colocar o que já tem feito e qual foi o problema encontrado.

Comment: Mostre o código, mostrando pelo menos os dados recebidos do sensor

Comment: já tenho a pergunta editada com o código

Comment: Amigo, primeiramente tente colocar o vec = [], fora da função apenas para ver se algo muda, senão, tente em seguida aumentar o número de medidas para além de 3000~4000, pois creio que antes do valor se alterar, o mesmo já preencheu todas as posições do vetor.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tudo bem?

O problema da repetição é devido a função `criaVetor`. Nela você adiciona na lista `vec` o mesmo valor `tam` vezes. Tenta adicionar os valores da lista dentro do while.

Veja essa sugestão:

```
#biblioteca para chamar ficheiros de outra extensão
from subprocess import check_output
import time

def Average(lst):
    return sum(lst)/len(lst)

tam = 100
count = 0
vec = []
while count<tam:
    # chama o ficheiro em linguagem C em modo diferencial
    sensor_data= check_output(['./raspandmax','-d'], shell=False).decode()
    output_value = (sensor_data)# mostra o valor analógico lido no ADC
    adc_value = float(output_value)# converte o valor analógico de string para float
    #print(adc_value)# mostra o valor da conversÃ£o

    vec.append(adc_values)
    time.sleep(1)
    count += 1

print(vec)
```